# Why does the I-75 have almost no tolls?

Tags: usa, driving, history, tolls

I-75 from Miami to Sarasota has almost no tolls, except when entering or leaving Naples.

I-95 in comparison has over $10 in tolls, at least.

I-95 may pass through larger cities, so that may be a reason. Is there a history behind almost no tolls on I-75?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. What does this matter to the traveler? As with tolls anywhere in the U.S., where they are charged and how much is largely dependent on politics, not infrastructure needs.

Comment: @choster may you please elaborate on infrastructure needs? I suppose there's less traffic on I-75 (less big cities), so did I completely answer the question?

Comment: There is no particular reason why tolls are set on one road versus another. It is largely a matter of when the roads were built and who the local politicians were and how the population was distributed and so on. But again, I do not understand how this is on-topic for this site. There probably isn't a stack for local transportation projects, unless [History.SE] wants it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a travel question.

Comment: I believe you are confusing I-95 with Florida's Turnpike. I-95 is subsidized by the Federal Interstate program. The turnpike is funded through tolls. I-95 has [tolls in Florida](http://www.i95exitguide.com/tolls/) only for use of the express lanes, which use congestion pricing.